# Status=401 - Full authentication is required to access this resource on server

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, vps

I successfully started the project in Spring + React on VPS, but when I type in the ip address and port, I get this error: 
**There was an unexpected error (type = Unauthorized, status = 401).** *in the browser* 
*And on the backend:* **Unauthorized error. Message - Full authentication is required to access this resource on server**

This is not very clear to me, **should the frontend part from the react be shown first so if I make a request to get this error?**

Since it seems to me that it does not recognize the frontend part, or am I wrong?

Comment: I think you are using spring security and maybe your endpoint is protected with @ResourceServer, Please share more details code, type of authentication/Authorization, etc.

Comment: @Lakshman I followed this tutorial: https://bezkoder.com/react-spring-boot-crud/ - https://bezkoder.com/spring-boot-jwt-authentication/

Comment: @Lakshman The problem is the same as here, only with me on vps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63737380/getting-unauthorized-error-full-authentication-is-required-to-access-this-resou